# Passing in section of array to BLAS Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, lapack, blas

I recently inherited a Fortran 2008 code where calls to BLAS/LAPACK are performed without the use of implicit interfaces. That has resulted into some cases where erroneous types of arguments get input e.g. reals being passed as integers.

My greater concern however is how arrays in general are passed into BLAS/LAPACK for example

```
call daxpy(n, da, dx(start), 1, dy(start), 1)
```

where `start` is a valid position in the arrays `dx` and `dy`.

My understanding is that by not supplying an explicit interface for `daxpy` we can get away with passing in a real instead of a real array. Furthermore, in the execution of the code I suspect BLAS/LAPACK see the memory address of `dx(start)` and assuming its contiguous access the next `n` entries. *Please correct me if I am wrong on this one*.

The above implementation (lack of explicit interfaces and passing only the start of arrays) makes me a bit uncomfortable, hence I decided to define the BLAS/LAPACK interfaces in the code. So the above call to `daxpy` has become

```
call daxpy(n, da, dx(start:), 1, dy(start:), 1)
```

My question is, is passing arrays like that considered good practice/safe? And moreover, is there any way to check/guarantee that no temporary arrays are created in the call?

Comment: _Sequence association_ applies whether the interface is explicit or implicit and is perfectly standard.

Comment: @francescalus thanks, so I take it that the second implementation is perfectly fine

Comment: The second is perfectly fine. There is no way to ensure a temporary object is not generated for any call in Fortran, it is implementation dependent. If you are worried about performance benchmark on the platform you are interested in - it is the only way to know for certain